# Google Contacts - Updating contact photo

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I'm using the Google API in C# and I'm trying to update a contact's photo.

The API already has a `ContactsRequest.SetPhoto` method, which technically should update the photo. However, I always receive the exception that

> Execution of request failed.

I also tried to manually make the request (based on API reference page) and got the same error again.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

(authentication: the contact entry "thisContact" is retrieved through an authorized connection. I'm also able to delete the photo through this session)

```
private void updateGContactPhoto(Contact thisContact, System.IO.Stream photoStream)
{
    GReqs.SetPhoto(thisContact, photoStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
the steam pointer has to be manually reset to 0 prior to upload:

```
photoStream.Position = 0;
```